# armadillo c++: Usage of cube data structure

Tags: armadillo

Is there a method to define a cube of vectors, like for e.g if I define cube(1,2,4), can I have every entry of the cube to be a vector of float entries (fcolvec) ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) always helps *before* posting questions.

To have vectors in a cube-like layout, use the [field class](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field):

```
field<vec> X(2,3,4);
```

Each of the elements in the field is then an instance of the [vec](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) class. You will still need to set the size of each vector and manipulate its contents. For example:

```
X(1,2,3).set_size(10);
X(1,2,3).fill(456);
```

If on the other hand you want to access the columns of a slice in a [cube](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube), use:

```
cube C(4,3,2, fill::zeros);

C.slice(1).col(2).fill(456);
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I was confused with the field class documentation. I assumed it holds a vector of arbitrary objects.